# How and where to add Servlet.jar to Weblogic 10?

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic

I have a web app that is failing I believe due to the lack the servlet.jar library. It works fine in tomcat, but fail with 500 error and no stack trace under Weblogic 10.

Should this be added with my web application under the WEB-INF/lib folder? Or should it be placed in the weblogic lib folder?

Comment: With no error messages included or deployment log from WebLogic your question will no likely be answered

Comment: What version of the servlet spec. are you developing against? 2.5? 3.0? What version of Tomcat did you run it on?

Comment: @NickWilson Tomcat 7, Version 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have gone tear-assing around your WLS installation you are *not* missing `servlet.jar`...

From WLS version 10 onwards, you will find it as `$BEA_HOME/modules/javax.servlet.x.y.z.jar`

Cheers,

Comment: Re. your comment to Nick: I'm fairly sure WLS 10 is only up to servlet spec 2.5, so if you're explicitly referencing version 3.0 you will need to add it to your artifact or WLS installation - I believe you can drop it in `<yourdomain>/server/lib` and it will be automatically added to the classpath.

Comment: Ahh.. That might just be the problem. I will add it. Thanks.